# AJAX request through angular js POST to a PHP script returning whole html page not redirecting

Tags: php, html, ajax, angularjs

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('br', []);
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.valid = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "php_files/login.php",
            data: {
                em: $scope.em,
                pw: $scope.pw
            },
        });

        request.success(function(data) {
            if (data == "invalid") {
                $scope.message = "Invalid email id or password!"
            }                
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="email"  required="required" ng-model="em"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" required="required" ng-model="pw" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="valid()"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align='center' style="color: red">{{message}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**PHP script**

```
include './include_db.php';
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$em = $request->em;
$pw = $request->pw;
$query = "select em,pw from users where em='$em' and pw='$pw'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$got_em = $row["em"];
$got_pw = $row["pw"];
if ($em != $got_em && $pw != $got_pw) {
    echo "invalid";
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["em"] = $em;
    header("Location:home.html");
}
```

Now what I want is if the email id and password is wrong it should return invalid which is working but if they are correct it should redirect to home page which is not working.

Comment: Not answering your question, but 1) use SHA1 to encrypt the passwords in your database, don't store them (or transmit them) in cleartext. 2) don't use mysql_XXX() methods in PHP. They are deprecatedhttp://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php use PDO  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Can you please explain **how** it is not working? Client or server side?

Comment: also, don't use mysql_ , it's deprecated long ago, and recently removed from PHP* , use mysqli_ or PDO ( http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers  ) - and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack from hackers! http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Also, after you "select em,pw from users where em='$em' and pw='$pw'" you can just check if you receive 1 row or zero. There is no point in checking if what you read out of the database is what you asked it to look for. If you get a row returned, then of course `$got_em` already `== $row["em"]` and `$got_pw == $row["pw"]` - that's what you searched for - you do not need to `if ($em != $got_em && $pw != $got_pw)`

Comment: If you don't want to retrieve the html for the new page, don't do it. Just get the target url and send redirect to it. Your PHP script that the AJAX calls can't do a redirect because it is sending back text to the current page! It looks like hanshenrik has given you a tip.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude,as you are new here & don't know yet. But you "thank" by uvoting, if you think it is worth it. And you don't post "tahhnks" comments, as it doesn't add anything & just makes it difficult to follow. I hope you got your answer

Comment: RaviChandraDurvasula thank you for thanking me, but as @Mawg mentioned, you can use upvotes for that. And if hanshenrik's answer solved your problem, you should probably upvote it and click the checkmark to mark it as the correct answer. If you don't feel the question is resolved yet, you can probably get more help in the comments or by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

in php_files/login.php:

```
if(!valid($username,$password)){
die("invalid");
} else {
die("https://logged_in_address");
}
```

in your javascript

```
                            request.success(function(data) {
                                if (data == "invalid") {
                                    $scope.message = "Invalid email id or password!"
                                } else {
                              window.location.replace(data);
/*redirect to the logged in page provided by login.php */
                               }
                            });
```